# Gradle method not found:'compile' possible causes : The Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

[image]

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'


        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

i'm trying to add compile method to build.gradle but i get this problem
i have android studio 3.5.2

and 5.4.1 gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `compile` with `implementation`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

But you are putting your dependencies in your `build.gradle` module Project. Place them in `build.gradle` module app.